# A static call problem in Java

Tags: java, static

I have a problem calling a static method from a class. Let me explain myself. 
I have an interface `Foo` and his implementation `FooImpl` which defines the method `getFoo();` :

```
public interface Foo {
   ...
   public A getFoo();

   ....
}

public class FooImpl implements Foo { 

    public A getFoo(){
        ....
        return new A();
    } 
}
```

This interface and his implementation is provided and I cannot modify them. In my program,  I define a class called `Bar` in which the method `getFoo` is always called:

```
public class Bar {

   Foo foo

   public void fooBar(){
         ......
         foo.getFoo()
         ....
   }
}
```

My problem is that I would to make a static call to the method `fooBar` of the class `Bar` but it is impossible since the method `getFoo` is not defined as static. 
For instance, I would like to do something like this :

```
public class Bar2 {

  public void execute(){
     Bar.fooBar()
  }
}
```

How can I achieve that ?

Thanks for your advice

**[EDIT]**
Sorry if I am not clear. The class Bar has a reference to Foo, so this is why it is possible to call `getFoo` in the class.  And I can guarantee that Foo/FooImpl are properly initialized (not by me) and I just use the informations provided by this interface.

Comment: Where's your `Foo` implementation in the `Bar` class?

Comment: Declare `Bar2.execute` as `static`? I don't think I understand your question. Can you elaborate on *why* you are trying to do this?

Comment: `getFoo()` implies `this.getFoo()` in your `fooBar()` example. However, if `Bar` doesn't extend `FooImpl` (or at least implement `Foo`), as it looks in your example, it's not clear what `getFoo()` is called on. What's the target object for `getFoo()`?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I am working on top of the Eclipse framework. Foo and FooImpl are provided and are properly initialized. @Bruno The target of Foo is a class (class A in this example) that has some information that I need.

Comment: You've added more info since I wrote my previous comment. With what you've written, the target is the *instance* in *field* `foo` of the current (`this`) instance of `Bar`. To achieve what you want you'd at least need to turn `Foo foo` and `void fooBar` in `Bar` into `static` members, as @Jon Skeet said (to remove any implicit usage of `this`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To call `Bar.fooBar()` in that way, it would *have* to be static, period.

You haven't shown how `Bar` gets an instance of `Foo` or `FooImpl` on which to call `getFoo()` - could there be a static `Foo` variable in `Bar` for example?

Basically there isn't enough information here, but sooner or later you'll have to have an instance of `FooImpl` *at least*, and quite possibly an instance of `Bar`, depending on its requirements.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you want something like this in `Bar`:

```
public static void fooBar() {
  ...
  Foo foo = new FooImpl();
  ...
  foo.getFoo();
  ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that.  The whole point of a non static method is that it requires an instance to be called against.

Typically, such a method will interact with the instance in some way like accessing its private data.  It also means that calls to the method on different instances can return different results.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `new Bar().fooBar();`

Answer (score 0):

You have to make sure to create an instance of `FooImpl` inside `static fooBar` method like this:

```
public static void fooBar(){
         Foo fooImpl = new FooImpl(); // create an isntance
         fooImpl.getFoo(); // call it
         ....
}
```